# Python web crawling/scraping - Download diagram(PDF or TIFF) from Webpage and save to Local machine

Tags: python, tiff

I have one website which has search button and i need to give some numeric value and give enter button. It will go to another page and it display some content in which  there are some URL, if i click that URL, it will ask to save diagram and the diagram is either tiff format or PDF.

To download Tiff format diagram, i am using swift plugin in internet explore and save to my machine

Here i am doing this work manually, just i want to do automate this whole process.

**Steps:**

1. Using python request module and pass the URL with numeric value to post method
2. save response content to variable
3. perform pattern matching and fetch url
4. click the url but i am stuck with this part to save the diagram local since it is tiff.

is there any module to download tiff based diagram and save to local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Just I want to share How i resolved the issue for the above question and it might be useful for others.

Since tiff image needs to be downloaded from web, so I used python request module with pillow module as below,

```
    from PIL import image
    import requests
    tiffURL='https://***.tif' 
    img=Image.open(requests.get(tiffURL,stream=True).raw)
    img.save('imagename.jpg')  
   #img.save('imagename.jpg',quality=95)
```

**Note:**

tiff image can not be viewed by normal editor , so i converted to  jpg
if you want high resoultion, you can pass quality=95 to save method